# Possible exposable asset type on Google Cloud

Tags: cloud-computing, monitoring, google-cloud-platform

One of the ways to secure a cloud environment is to monitor all of the assets that we have. Recently, I made a script to get information regarding those assets by using GCP API, but I need to do it one by one, for each asset by using the `describe` command to determine if it is public or not.

Do you know which asset type on Google Cloud that can be publicly accessible? I found some but I want to make sure that I cover every asset type that can be public.

Here is what I found:

1. Bucket
2. Instance
3. Firewall
4. Forwarding Rule
5. Backend Service
6. Cluster
7. Storage

Is there anything else that I missed? or is there a way to get all information regarding public asset on GCP?

Comment: Please clarify what's your criteria for clasiffying a resource as public, what's the `gcloud` command you use to deternine that ? What's your goal here ?

Comment: hello there, for example in Forwarding Rules i use `gcloud compute forwarding-rules describe NAME --format=json` from [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/forwarding-rules/describe) and it will show a json file with keys and values. This is the keys and values [link](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1/python/latest/compute_v1.forwardingRules.html) One of the key is `loadBalancingScheme` which value can be `EXTERNAL` or `INTERNAL`. If it is `EXTERNAL` it is possibly exposable to internet with external IP Address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may be confusing few things so let me explain what's what.

**There's no such distinctiomn in GCP services as Public (or external) and internal.**

Some of the - like [Load Balancers](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview) are designed to work both ways - depending on what you need. Sometime you want to distribute big amounts of traffic between you VM's (or other backend services) and sometimes between your VM's in you project or just a single VPC network.

**[Buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets)** store data - by default they are visible only to people that have permisions to read their contents. To [make them available](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-set-bucket-public-iam) from Internet you have to explicitly make that choice and assign specific permissions (hardly something that can be done accidentally).

**[VM instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute)** by default get Public IP (however it's NAT'ed). You can choose to get only internal IP - this way they are only visible to other VM's in the same VPC network.

**Forwarding rules and [backend services](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service)** are a part of Load Balancers which I explained earlier.

**[Cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine)** is a group of VM's working together to achieve better scalability for your services. By default single VM's in the GKE cluster get external IP and can be accessed from the Internet but you can choose for them to only have internal IP's. In this case you can really get Private or Public cluster.

**[Storage](https://cloud.google.com/products/storage)** - there are several options here - buckets are just one of them. Most widely used are disks used to run and store data in your VM's. They however are designed to be available to VM's inside GCP.

There are many other [GCP services](https://cloud.google.com/products) - have a look at linked documentaiton to understand the basics.

Comment: hello thank you for the answer good Sir,  is there any other possible type that can be public / have external IP other than you said? thank you very much for the answer. I cant click on the `GCP services` link that you provided

Comment: Additionally you can access CloudSQL instances, App engine apps, cloud run apps etc. If you're using [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn) to connect your on-premise network with the one in GCP you're also exposing this service to the Internet.